# How to fix a library's dependency on node-only modules

Tags: node.js, typescript, browser, frontend

This is about https://github.com/ecadlabs/taquito/.
This library usable from both node applications, and browser applications. But we assume the majority should be using it from the browser.

When added to an angular project, I get this error in developer tools:

> browser-external:buffer:9 Module "buffer" has been externalized for browser compatibility. Cannot access "buffer.Buffer" in client code. See https://vitejs.dev/guide/troubleshooting.html#module-externalized-for-browser-compatibility for more details

Similar errors in other frontend stacks.

I tried:

1. changing our rollup config to polyfill these,
2. tried parcel (that says it does this polyfill automatically, with no configuration)
3. tried microbundle

no matter what I do, I cannot remove this warning.

This dependency on `buffer` probably comes from one of our dependencies.

What is the right way to fix this?

Please note that I need to fix **my library**, so that users can consume it without needing any polyfills

**EDIT: Being more specific:**

C--dependeson-->B--depends on-->A--uses-->`buffer`

- Let's say Library `A` is using a node specific module, like `buffer`
- **I'm developing Library** `B`, which depends on `A`
- Other people are writing their apps, let's call them `C`

Now if I don't do anything, people need to polyfill their apps (`C`). I want to do that in `B`. So that it's done once, and I create a good developer experience for them. We have complete control over `B`, but no control over `A` and we want to make things work out of box for people doing `C`

Comment: I don't see how you can make it "just work" for non-Node users as the library author except by using the polyfills for all users, rather than relying on the native node modules.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Also a library author. For me one of my goals for all my (frontend) libraries is that they are small and very low in dependencies. Important for Node, but way more important for browsers.

By far the best way to universally fix this, is to try to figure out which of your dependencies uses Buffer, and remove this dependency.

Many NPM packages exist that are frontend-friendly. If they use Buffer, they are explicitly not and inflate your bundle. Sometimes you can simply inline whatever you needed from a dependency, and sometimes you can find alternative. If the functionality the dependency provided was somewhat small, just copy it in and reduce your dependency tree.

Comment: Thanks Evert. Is there any good resource for library authors to learn best practices? I feel everyone needs to learn the same things the hard way?

Comment: @Alireza I'm not aware of a concise, specific resource. I would say I learned the 'hard way', but it's a pretty interesting journey, and each open source project you produce will be better than the last.

Comment: That is interesting. With two million packages on npmjs, hundreds of thousands of people should have gone through this journey "the hard way".

Comment: @Alireza im not saying a good resource doesn't exist, just that I don't have one for you. Also most packages are bad

Comment: Thanks Evert. Even if it exists, it's not easy to discover. I searched a bit for that. There are fragmented information here and there, but I could not find a good resource. Also agree with your last sentence :)

Answer (score 0):

The error message you're encountering indicates that the library you're using relies on Node.js-specific features (in this case, the buffer module), which are not natively available in the browser environment. This situation is common when using libraries that are built to support both Node.js and the frontend, but certain Node.js modules need polyfills or equivalents to work in the browser.

The most straightforward way is to use a polyfill like `feross/buffer` which is specifically designed to mimic the Buffer API in the browser.

Comment: Please note that I'm the library creator. I don't want to fix the app, I want to fix the library, so that no app needs this fix.

Comment: Use feross/buffer in the library...

Comment: Can you please see the updated question?